# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined TypeScript

Tags: typescript, npm

I am trying to export namespace from one `.ts` file and import from other `.ts` file and getting an error `NewMain.ts:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. I was new and actually learning TypeScript. Here is my `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
     "module": "commonjs",
     "noImplicitAny": true,
     "removeComments": true,
     "preserveConstEnums": true,
     "sourceMap": true
 },
 "files": [
     "greeter.ts",
     "Main.ts",
     "RajIsh.ts",
     "NewMain.ts"        
  ],
 "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Here is my `NewMain.ts` where I am importing name space

```
 import {DepartmentSection} from "./RajIsh"
 class Employee{
     name: string;
     //Function
     Display(username:string)
     {
         this.name=username;
         console.log(this.name);
     }
 }
 var person = new Employee();
 var itCell= new DepartmentSection.ITCell("Information Technology Section");
 console.log("Displaying from NewMain.ts by importing......");
 console.log(person.Display("XYZ")+" belongs to "+  itCell.DisplaySectionName("Finance Revenue and Expenditure Section"));
 console.log("Wooooooooo Hurrey!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!......");
```

and here is my namespace in `RajIsh.ts`

```
 export namespace DepartmentSection {
    export class Section  {
        //===================Class Property by default public
        name: string;

        //==================Constructor of Section Class taking parameter of Employee Name
        constructor(theName: string) {

                this.name = theName;
            }
        //====================Function which displays the department name of a person
        Department(depatmentName: string = "") {
            console.log(`${this.name} ,  ${depatmentName} !!`);
        }

    }
      //============================================================================================
      //=========================Inheritance

    export class ITCell extends Section{
        constructor(SectionName: string) { 
            super(SectionName); 
        }
        DisplaySectionName(DepartmentName:string) {
            console.log("Printing Section name...");
            super.Department(DepartmentName);
        }

    }
     export class LoanAndAccount extends Section {
        constructor(SectionName: string) { 
            super(SectionName); 
        }
        DisplaySectionName(DepartmentName:string) {
            console.log("Printing another Section name...");
            super.Department(DepartmentName);
        }
    }

 }
```

Where m I doing wrong? I tried to import like this as well `import DepartmentSection = require('./RajIsh');` but when I try to access the class and function it is throwing an error saying `Property 'ITCell' does not exist on type 'typeof' RajIsh`. What should I need to do?

Comment: have you tried exporting only the class without using the namespace? by removing this line `export namespace DepartmentSection ` and importing individual class in ts file

Comment: it throws error `Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined`  in this line `define("RajIsh", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports)`

Comment: Are you looking for module or namespace? because you are following the import style of module in ES6 typescrpt

Comment: I am looking for namespace....

Comment: you don't have to use `export` and `import` when you use namespaces. Instead, you can just use `namespace Test { class Thing }` in one file, and then in another file you can use the class by doing `let n = new Test.Thing()`. No need for a module bundler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have came across the same problem some time back and I have resolved by using `SystemJs`. Try using `Systemjs`. Install SystemJs from command line using npm `npm install systemjs` and implement in your Index.html in this way in the `head` section

```
 <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>

 <script>
    SystemJS.config({
    baseURL:"/", //Can write the path like /script and the browser will look inside the script folder
    packages:{
        ".":{
            defaultExtension:'js'
        }
    }
  })
  SystemJS.import("./main.js")
 <script>
```

Try this it should run. Hope it helps you.

Comment: An alternate option is require.js which is extremely nice because it runs on one line of code... you just define what the main script is and then you can use require() throughout.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the typescript compiler to bundle your `.ts` files together into one `main.js` file, you don't need `import` and `export` at all!

`require` and `import` only work when you use a module bundler - it's not included in typescript!

You can choose to use `namespace` to organise your code, but it's not necessary.

**file thing.ts**

```
namespace Test {
    class Thing {
    }
}
```

**file app.ts**

```
namespace Main {
    class App {
        constructor(){
             // you can make a new Thing instance here without import!
             let n = new Test.Thing()
        }
    }
}
```

This works because the namespaces are actually in the global scope, so you can call them from anywhere. Module bundlers like webpack keep your code private (unavailable in the global scope) and that's why you need to use `import` and `export` with webpack.

Comment: I get the error "app.ts(5,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Test'."